# What determines the Person Account Record Type pre-selected when converting a Lead

Tags: record-type, lead-conversion, person-accounts

I am converting a Lead into a Person Account.

I have two Person Account record types: `Person A` and `Person B`

My profile has record type `Person A` is my default Person Account record type.

But when the Lead convert dialog appears, it has `Person B` record type pre-selected.

According to this Salesforce help article: [Mapping Lead Record Type to Account Record Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004455&language=en_US&type=1)

> When a Lead is converted to an Account, the Lead Record Type does not
>   map over to the Account Record Type. The account record created
>   through Lead Conversion will not be based on the record type of the
>   user who converted the lead, instead it uses the default record type
>   assigned to the profile of the specified record owner during Lead
>   conversion.

But this is not what I am seeing. Currently there are only two users in the Org and we both have the same profile and `Person A` is the default Person Account record type.

How can I change it such that `Person A` is pre-selected?

Comment: is it standard lead conversion? or some URL hack passing recordTypeId in url params?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal it's standard. I wasn't of Lead conversion URL hackery until now!

Comment: Are there any account triggers or Lead Conversion triggers?

Comment: @SebastianKessel nope, no triggers, it's a brand new org

Comment: Official documentation states that **"If the lead has a record type, the default record type of the user converting the lead is assigned to records created during lead conversion."** which unfortunately doesn't address the lead conversion dialog selection.

Comment: @MarkPond I read that also, which is why I checked what the default record type for my profile was.